# Why Css folder inside Assets folder path not getting in Android Studio after convert from Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, webview, assets

I have one Project that i have converted from Eclipse to Android Studio.I am loading webpage from asset folder.I have many folder inside assets folder like css,js,fonts etc.My project work perfectly in Eclipse but when i converted it in Android Studio then web page not load from Asset Folder.What resoan behind this ?

Comment: Can you tell me the path name of the web page?

Comment: The body of your post does not reflect the subject. Please tell what is really the problem as now your post makes no sense.